# Drag 2 dot images and create a line between them in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to asked some suggestions on how will I achieve to do this below scenario:

I would like to drag a two dot in any location I want in a web page. Then I will click the first dot and click the second dot. After I clicked them it should generate a line that connects them. And also the should save in the database.

Guys, could u give me some suggestions on how can I do it?

Thanks

I get some picture here below:

[image]

Comment: you can try d3.js http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to answer your question without more details about what it is exactly you are trying to achieve.

But this sounds like a html5 canvas element problem. But like I said, I can only provide more help when I understand what it is that you are trying to do.